Quarkus Form-Based Auth: How to Keep Users Logged In After Closing the Browser?
I have a Quarkus application with JDBC/JPA form-based authentication. The login process works fine, but I would like users to stay logged in for some time, even after closing the browser.
I've set the following properties, thinking they would solve my problem:
quarkus.http.auth.form.timeout=P7D  
quarkus.http.auth.form.new-cookie-interval=P1D

However, these don't seem to have any effect in this regard. In Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that the cookie's "Expiration / Max-Age" is set to "session."
Is this the correct way to implement a "Remember Me" functionality, or am I missing something?
Note: I am also using OIDC auth and I haven't had any issues to configure this.

can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?
